# Django associate form values to user

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm very new to Django but I started to create a project and I need some help. My question is very basic but I can't find the right answer.

I made a questionnaire that works fine but I don't know how to do that if a logged in user adds his answers Django associate the answers to the user.

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import Stressz_teszt
from .forms import StresszForm
from django.forms import ModelForm

def stressz_item(request):
form = StresszForm(request.POST or None)

if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return redirect('stressz/login.html')

return render(request, 'stressz/stressz-form.html', {'form':form})
```

**Urls.py**

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path
from django.forms import ModelForm
    
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    
    #stressz teszt form
    path('add', views.stressz_item, name='stressz_item'),
    path('<int:item_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Stressz_teszt

class StresszForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Stressz_teszt
        fields = ['stressz_v01', 'stressz_v02', 'stressz_v03', 'stressz_v04', 'stressz_v05',] ...
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Stressz_teszt(models.Model):

def __str__(self):
    return self.stressz_name

user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
stressz_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
stressz_company = models.CharField(max_length=300)
stressz_v01 = models.IntegerField()
stressz_v02 = models.IntegerField()
stressz_v03 = models.IntegerField()
stressz_v04 = models.IntegerField()
stressz_v05 = models.IntegerField()
...
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
def stressz_item(request):
    if form.is_valid():
        stressz_teszt = form.save(commit=False)
        stressz_teszt.user_name = request.user
        stressz_teszt.save()
        return redirect('stressz/login.html')
    return render(request, 'stressz/stressz-form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thank you! It saves the form but the user field is empty.

Comment: Are you sure the user is authenticated ? Try to print `request.user`

Comment: I think I found the problem. If I make a new user from the admin panel it works fine but if I use the registration form the user can log in but the new user does not appear in the admin panel. It's very confusing to me.

I found that vs code underlines a line with yellow so it can't find my users module but I don't know why, I can't find any mistakes.

from users import views as user_views